# How to get dojo module path from inside of a widget

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have dojoConfig as below:

```
var base = location.href.split("/");
base.pop();
base = base.join("/");

var dojoConfig = {
      async: true,
      parseOnLoad: false,
      isDebug: false,

      packages: [{
        name: "library",
        location: base + '/js/lib'
      }, {
        name: 'widgets',
        location: base + '/js/widgets'
      }];
```

How to access the `location` of `widgets` from inside of another loaded module or widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from the [official site](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/moduleUrl.html), `dojo/require` does that.

Here is an example:

```
require(["dojo/_base/xhr", "dojo/dom"], function(xhr, dom){
     // points to $dojoroot/dijit/form/tests/TestFile.html
     var url = require.toUrl("dijit/form/tests/TestFile.html");
     xhr.get({
         url: url,
         load: function(html){
             dom.byId("foo").innerHTML = html;
         }
     });
});
```